# Filtering array of Objects Using Lodash or Javascript based on property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I am Having the Array of objects. Like this

```
var result=[{"batchId":123, "licenseId":2345ef34, "name":"xxx"},
{"batchId":345, "licenseId":2345sdf334, "name":"www"},
{"batchId":145, "licenseId":234sdf5666, "name":"eee"},
{"batchId":455, "licenseId":asfd236645 },
{"batchId":678, "name":"aaa"}]
```

i want to have the array which is contains all the three properties. the Output should be like this.

```
[{"batchId":123, "licenseId":2345ef34, "name":"xxx"},
    {"batchId":345, "licenseId":2345sdf334, "name":"www"},
    {"batchId":145, "licenseId":234sdf5666, "name":"eee"}]
```

can anybody Help me on this

Answer (score 4):

This is simple with the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var result=[
  {"batchId":123, "licenseId":"2345ef34", "name":"xxx"},
  {"batchId":345, "licenseId":"2345sdf334", "name":"www"},
  {"batchId":145, "licenseId":"234sdf5666", "name":"eee"},
  {"batchId":455, "licenseId":"asfd236645" },
  {"batchId":678, "name":"aaa"}
];

var filtered = result.filter(function(v) {
      return "batchId" in v && "licenseId" in v && "name" in v;
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

The function you pass to `.filter()` is called for each element in the array. Each element for which you return a truthy value will be included in the resulting array.

In the code above I simply test if all three of those specific properties are present, although there are other tests you could use that would get the same result for that data:

```js
var result=[ {"batchId":123, "licenseId":"2345ef34", "name":"xxx"}, {"batchId":345, "licenseId":"2345sdf334", "name":"www"}, {"batchId":145, "licenseId":"234sdf5666", "name":"eee"}, {"batchId":455, "licenseId":"asfd236645" }, {"batchId":678, "name":"aaa"} ];

var filtered = result.filter(function(v) {
      return Object.keys(v).length === 3;
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

Note that you need to put your `licenseId` values in quotes, because they seem to be string values.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = [{
  "batchId": 123,
  "licenseId": '2345ef34',
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "batchId": 345,
  "licenseId": '2345sdf334',
  "name": "www"
}, {
  "batchId": 145,
  "licenseId": '234sdf5666',
  "name": "eee"
}, {
  "batchId": 455,
  "licenseId": 'asfd236645'
}, {
  "batchId": 678,
  "name": "aaa"
}];

function hasProperties(object) {
  return object.hasOwnProperty('batchId') && object.hasOwnProperty('licenseId') && object.hasOwnProperty('name')
}

result.filter(e => hasProperties(e));
```

Comment: Nice one. You could even write `result.filter(hasProperties);`.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks. I didn't know.